# Transform Data Set Using Pandas

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, data-science

I'm trying to transform how my data looks. I am trying to transform it from this:

| Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3 | Feature 4 | Target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.2 | 0.5 | 2.1 | 7.8 | 15.3 |
| 11.5 | 0.7 | 1.8 | 7.0 | 16.2 |
| 9.8 | 0.6 | 2.2 | 8.5 | 14.5 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 12.3 | 0.9 | 1.4 | 6.2 | 17.6 |
| 11.7 | 0.8 | 1.7 | 6.5 | 16.8 |
| 10.9 | 0.7 | 2.0 | 7.3 | 15.9 |

to this:

| Date/Time | Target Variable |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00 | 10.2 |
| 2000-01-01 01:00:00 | 11.5 |
| 2000-01-01 02:00:00 | 9.8 |
| ... | ... |
| 2017-12-31 21:00:00 | 12.3 |
| 2017-12-31 22:00:00 | 11.7 |
| 2017-12-31 23:00:00 | 10.9 |

[Here is a link to what my current data looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34BRv.png)

I looked at the pandas documentation, but I had no luck figuring out how to achieve this result with my data set.

Comment: Can you clarify how the first table relates to the second table? It is unclear how, on paper, one would transform the first into the second.

Comment: Certainly, There is no relation really as it's more of a transformation issue. In the first table, I want the column data to be as an index date time as shown in the second table, and the corresponding data next to itas the target variables.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to get it to go from wide to long, you can use `df.melt()` based on your data.

```
data = {2008: [10,20,30,40,50],
        2009: [60,70,80,90,100],
        2010: [110, 120, 130, 140, 150]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_long = df.melt().rename({'variable': 'year'})
```

```
    year  value
0   2008     10
1   2008     20
2   2008     30
3   2008     40
4   2008     50
5   2009     60
6   2009     70
7   2009     80
8   2009     90
9   2009    100
10  2010    110
11  2010    120
12  2010    130
13  2010    140
14  2010    150
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm trying to do, and I reach this far, but how can I have instead of multiple 2008 years just one with each value increasing like value 1, value 2 , value 3 ect.

Comment: How do you want to aggregate the values to year? There are multiple values per year, so they need to be aggregated to collapse into a single row. Do you want it to look like `2008-1 2008-2 2008-3`?

Comment: I want it to look like  0   2008  10  20 30
                                  1  2009    60 70 80


so the values continue for that one year and not showing multiple years in the index.

Comment: This is very different from your original question.

Comment: No, not different maybe I didn't explain effectively but this is the outcome i am looking for. Sorry for the confusion.